# how to click on "a" tag or button on a webpage using <Table> and <td> and <tr>?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to click on the first Ref number "*182931*" with name of Request ID "350-ageing replica" only out of two report i trying forloop in excelVBA & tried many method but nothing happen i have attchdad two image kindly check & help.

[check this image][1]
[check this image][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I311.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chrUD.png

```
Sub VSV_Ageing_Download()

Dim IE As Object

Dim Button
Dim Button2
Dim Button3
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error Resume Next

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                        
IE.Top = 0
IE.Left = 0
IE.Width = 1000
IE.Height = 1050
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "MY link"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
Loop

IE.document.all.Item("username").Value = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
IE.document.all.Item("password").Value = "xxxxxxxxxxx"


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
Do While IE.Busy

Loop

For Each Button2 In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If Button2.Type = "submit" Then
 Button2.Click
 Exit For
 End If
 Next

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
 Do While IE.Busy

 Loop

  For Each MYCELLS In Rng

  IE.document.all.Item("circleId").Value = "my data"
  IE.document.forms(4).submit

  For Each Button2 In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  If Button2.Value = "Go" Then
  Button2.Click
  Exit For
  End If
  Next


 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
 Do While IE.Busy

 Loop

 For Each Button2 In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
 If Button2.Value = "Request Management" Then
 Button2.Click
 Exit For
 End If
 Next


 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
 Do While IE.Busy

 Loop


 For Each Button2 In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  If Button2.Value = "Monitor Request Status" Then
 Button2.Click
 Exit For
 End If
 Next

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
 Do While IE.Busy
 Loop

 IE.document.all.Item("loginId").Value = "my id"
 IE.document.forms(5).submit

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
  Do While IE.Busy

 Loop
     'i am stuck at below code kindly help on this
     For Each Button2 In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
     If Button2.Title = "Click Here to Download the Report" Then
     Button2.Click
     Exit For
     End If
     Next

  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
  Do While IE.Busy

  Loop

   Next

   End Sub
```

kindly help on this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the loop and use a css selector list that looks for the td shown in image and match using class. Then move to the child anchor tag, which would be matched as a direct child using the child combinator (>).

Additionally, I would specify that the child anchor tag must have a title attribute containing the string "Download the Report" (case sensitive):

```
IE.document.querySelector("td.tableDataFont > a[title*='Download the Report']").click
```

No need for a loop.